# How to change the format into simple date/time format-jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert : `2015-09-13T08:09:09.0Z`time format into: `Sept13, 2015 08:08:09 AM`where,

08: hours
08: mins
09: secs
and AM/PM depending on what time it is. Any idea how can i achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [toLocaleString() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), it does that, except it will return the date as 9/13/2015, and convert the time to the person's local time. Implementation would be:

```
var date = new Date("2015-09-13T08:09:09.0Z");
date.toLocaleString();
// returns "9/13/2015, 4:09:09 AM" in the Eastern Time Zone.
```

You could use other methods on the date object of course, to get the exact desired effect, but it would be quite a bit of logic to write out. Alternatively, you can have a look at an excellent library called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which does the heavy lifting for you. First example on their homepage does what you described.